# Can call method even after logout and session clear from postman

Tags: asp.net, security, session, proxy, logout

I need to resolve an issue related to security of one of my projects. One of the issues is that I can call some events even after I log out using the proxy. 
This issue occurs using postman, burp and some other proxy clients. Below is what I have done on log out.

```
Protected Sub mnuSignOut_click(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As Ext.Net.DirectEventArgs)
    Try
        If Not UserIdentity() Is Nothing Then
            Dim objLoginHistory As New TblUserLoginHistory
        objLoginHistory.UpdateLogOutHistory(UserIdentity.UserLoginHistoryID)
        End If
        Session.Abandon()
        Session.Clear()
        Response.Cookies.Add(New HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""))
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(New HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""))
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
        Ext.Net.X.AddScript("window.top.location.href='" & GetServerURL() & "/login.aspx';")
    Catch ex As Exception
        LogError(ex, Request.RawUrl & "->" & strPageName & " -> mnuSignOut_click()")
    End Try
End Sub
```

As can be seen, I have cleared session value, abandon and removed value from the cookie. But none works for me.

Scenario: I am capturing a specific event in postman client. Now when I log out from the system and will send older request from the postman, it fires and all my data changes as changed and requested from the postman.

I want to know that what is wrong with the logout flow. Is there anything I am missing to do on log out event. I want no events to be fired once I log out from the system.

Comment: To my memory, this is inherent in how .Net does sessions without using persistent storage.  Of course deleting the cookie will delete it from the browser, not the proxy.  The only way to fix this is with a database that has persistent session information.  But then you end up doing completely different session management.  So generally, you will see the same problem in many .Net applications (I learned this from pentesting).

Comment: What [Session-State Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) are you using?  I suspect that this problem might go away if you are using SQLServer, but it would need to be tested to confirm.